# How to hide an element on click instead of timeout using Clippy.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a neat little JS library called [Clippy.js](https://www.smore.com/clippy-js) that lets you implement Microsoft Word's old virtual assistants in your browser. After playing around with it for a while I realized that the text balloon has a `setTimeout()` method and a time delay causing it to disappear.

```
    hide:function (fast) {
        if (fast) {
            this._balloon.hide();
            return;
        }

        this._hiding = window.setTimeout($.proxy(this._finishHideBalloon, this), this.CLOSE_BALLOON_DELAY);
    },

    _finishHideBalloon:function () {
        if (this._active) return;
        this._balloon.hide();
        this._hidden = true;
        this._hiding = null;
    },
```

I don't want that. I want the balloon to disappear when a user clicks. I tried registering an event listener by replacing `this._hiding = ...` with this:

```
var clickToHide = document.getElementsByClassName('clippy-balloon');
this._hiding = clickToHide.addEventListener('click', function(){$.proxy(this._finishHideBalloon, this)});
```

...but all that it does is hide the balloon completely. Why does that not work? And how do I achieve the functionality I want?

Comment: Based on the code you have here, I think `this` inside the click function you defined has a different context than `this` in `this._hiding`; try setting a `var that` to `this` and using `that` inside the click function...that may fix the issue

Comment: Like this, right? `this._hiding = clickToHide.addEventListener('click', function(){
            var that = this._hiding;
            $.proxy(that._finishHideBalloon, that)
        });`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You would need to move the initialization of `that` outside the function, so something like this:
`var that = this;`
`this._hiding = clickToHide.addEventListener('click', function(){$.proxy(that._finishHideBalloon, that)});`
Just a hunch as to what the problem may be...

Comment: Does not seem to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the delay is caused by the variable `CLOSE_BALLOON_DELAY`.
Changing `this.CLOSE_BALLOON_DELAY` to `0` should do the trick.

Comment: That entire line of code was replaced with my attempt at an eventListener, so that can't be the case.

Comment: why did you use `this.finishHideBalloon` instead of `this._finishHideBalloon` ?

Comment: That was a typo. I fixed it, and it doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: try once without assigning the event handler to `this._hiding`.

`var clickToHide = document.getElementsByClassName('clippy-balloon');clickToHide.addEventListener('click', function(){$.proxy(this._finishHideBalloon, this)});`

Comment: It did not. I have some brushing up to do. Thanks for your help!